# How to handle REST API session expiry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, session

We have a mobile app (built using phonegap) accessing data from a REST API. This rest API has an authorization token specific to us - provided by them after registering with them. Now, we are using the API access URL with the token issued.

E.g. `(http://api.something.com/cities/buildings/auth_token=blahblah)`. We are able to get the data through an AJAX request - which obviously has a SUCCESS and an ERROR callback function.

I understand now that there is an expiry for this session, and this is where I am stuck. My AJAX request fails and the control goes to the ERROR callback after a few mins. In my whole app, I do not have a login screen (I don't want to have one).

The AJAX request is being called on a button click. So, when I click this button for the first time, my data comes out successfully. But when my session expires, I get an error message (the message that I defined in my AJAX error callback).
Here, if I click the same button again, the session gets established and I am getting my data again.

Shortly ->

Step 1. Click the button -> Data retrieval successful

Step 2. Session expires

Step 3. Click the button -> Error message appears

Step 4. Click the same button again -> Data retrieval successful

Now my question is how to handle this scenario? Is my understanding of this particular REST API correct?

My expectation is to eliminate Step 3, Is that possible? Any workaround? Or should the user follow all these steps for sure, everytime a session expires?

Comment: There isn't a general answer to this, as this is a specific REST API. You would have to contact them and ask them to increase the session lifetime. A fallback would be to ping the API every X minutes in the background to make sure your session stays alive. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Chris - I think, pinging the API in the background is something that I can try

Comment: I think, pinging the API in the background may kill the battery if its a mobile based application

Comment: You have to check if the user is authed and has a valid session on your server I guess before sending API calls with your auth token.